# How to configure the trap command to make it run after a process ends that is started with nohup?

Tags: trap

I'm using a `tmpfile` and pass it to `my_exe` in my shell script. I need to remove the `tmpfile` after `my_exe` is terminated, so I use `trap "rm $tmpfile" exit`.

I also need to prevent `my_exe` from closing when I close the terminal, so I use `nohup my_exe $tmpfile &`. However, as this causes my script to terminate, the `$tmpfile` is deleted immediately, before `my_exe` could read it. Here is how it looks like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=$(mktemp)
trap "rm $tmpfile" exit

echo "aaa" > $tmpfile

nohup my_exe $tmpfile &
```

How can I configure `trap` command to make it wait actually for `my_exe` to terminate?

Comment: Don't start your `my_exe` in the background? Is there a specific reason you start `my_exe` as a background job?

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your script invokes `my_exe` in the background.  This means the invocation of `my_exe` returns immediately with a success code.

As far as your script can tell, `my_exe` was invoked and completed its work successfully.  Your script has no further commands to perform, so your script exits, and this triggers the trap that deletes the temp file.

You can't configure the trap to behave the way you ask because trap is not an external command.  It's an internal function of the shell that's running the script.  In order to make the trap function wait for `my_exe` to finish, the script must wait for `my_exe` to finish.

Since you've said you want to close your terminal while `my_exe` runs, I suggest you remove the & from the line invoking `my_exe`.  Your script will wait for `my_exe` to finish using the temp file.  Instead, run your script in the background with &.

It may take some experimentation to get it to function the way you want.  I would suggest testing with a version of the script that invokes `/bin/sleep 15` instead of `my_exe` to verify you can close your terminal window without killing the processes and the temp file is removed at the right time.